# Cookies:Backend is working good but Front end is not accepting the cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, cors, mern

I have been working on MERN stack sending cookie to front end but there is some problem in Front end part most probably in header .... Everything is working on postman but now working when im fetching data from React.
[There is NOOOOOO Cookie coming in localstorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfIGN.png)

In frontEnd:

This the router I'm woking with  backend "index.js"

```
app.post("/login",async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const val1 = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email})
        const val2= await User.findOne({email:req.body.email,password:req.body.password})
        
        if(val1 && val2){
            const token =await jwt.sign({id:val2._id},process.env.SECRET,{expiresIn:"1hr"})
            const rest=await User.updateOne({_id:val2._id},{tokens:{token:token}})
            res.cookie("jwttoken",token,{
                expires:new Date(Date.now() + 3600*1000),
                httpOnly:true,
                secure:false

            })
            
            res.json({message:"success"})
        }else if(!val2 && val1){
            res.json({message:"wrongpass"})
        }else{
            res.json({message:"failure"})
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error: in /login",err)
        res.json({message:"failure"})
    }
})
```

frontend in app/LoginPage ///// Important  is function loginApi> fetching .... what should we do in HEADERS

```
 const loginApi = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        // Replace with your actual API call and implement logic
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/login', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Accept:"application/json",
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
            },
              body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        });
        // to handle response and authentication
        console.log(response)
        const message= await response.json()
        
        return message
      };
    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        // Basic email validation
        if (!email.includes('@') || !email.includes('.')) {
          setErrorMessage('Invalid email format');
          return;
        }
      
        // Call login API function here (replace with your actual implementation)
        try {
          const response = await loginApi(email, password);
          console.log(response.message)
          if (response.message==="success") {
            // Login successful - navigate to Add Products Page
            const hasCookie = document.cookie;
            console.log("Cookie presence:", hasCookie); 
            //navigate('/addproduct');
          } else if(response.message ==="wrongpass"){

            setErrorMessage('Login failed password is wrong');
            navigate('/login')
          }else{
            setErrorMessage('Please Sign in you are not registered')
          }
          setEmail("")
          setPassword("")
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Login error:', error);
          setErrorMessage('An error occurred. Please try again.');
        }
      };
```